# What is positive thinking? How is it developed?

Tags: philosophy, mind, consciousness, buddhi

Many philosophers, Gurus and Acharyas stress on "positive way of life" or "positive thinking".
If the "negative thinking" was so bad, then it would have vanished from general populace with time, isn't it?

What is the non-dual meaning of "positive thinking", Is it *faith / श्रद्धा*?

More importantly, how one develops "positivism" inside the mind?
For example, if someone says that, "be positive!" How to get the pre-requisite to be able to "be positive"?

<sub>Related: [How and why was the first ever thought generated?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24906/1049)</sub>

Comment: Shouldn't this question belong to philosophy? Positive thoughts are not just associated with Hinduism but in fact all religions or are you asking it only with respect to Hinduism? If yes Swami Vivekananda's books may give you an answer.

Comment: @adithskv, this Qn is expecting answers from Hinduism perspective, but not necessarily ancient works. I am fine if someone answers from non Hindu perspective as well. It's tagged with "philosophy" due to its nature. I find it redundant to mention "according to Hinduism". You may quote Vivekananda, if you have found the answer already.

Answer (score 4):

Here, I just tried to explain positive energy and How to boost up it with a different method and one example. It is all about human being not Just for Hinduism.

**Positive Energy:**

It is just not sawing anyone. It is just like to realize it. Every those activity which is good for you, good for society, build your self-confidence and create a positive power in your body. in Short when you feel

**असतो मा सद्गमय ।(Untruth To Truth)
तमसो मा ज्योतिर्गमय ।(Darkness to Light)
मृत्योर्मा अमृतं गमय ।(Death to Birth)**

This type of feeling then understands positive energy within you.

There are some methods to increase positive power within you.

**Keep always positive mind:**

To build up positive energy think it is necessary to that your mind should keep positive means if you some work in your hand then don't put away until its completion. during completing, this work there are numbers of problems will arise but you don't get loose your confidence. keep always in your mind…

“I can do anything”

“Nothing is impossible in this world”

Determine small goals and try to achieve them:

To do anything work there is first to set your goals that means select destination which you achieve in future. so, try to set a small goal and choose the right way to achieve them.

**Try to keep smiley in your face:**

“if you can change anybody's tear int smile then you can do anything”

It is not easy to keep smiley in the face at any time but it is done but using when you feel bored at that time you listen songs or jokes and also play your favourite games.

**Meditation, yoga and concentration:**

To boost up positive energy, we must control our mind. So, we must do meditation for our mental health and must do yoga and exercise for physical health. every time we must concentrate on our predetermined goal. so, our mind creates a way to achieve that goal.

“Yoga is the journey of the self, to the self, through the self ”

**Encourage yourself:**

When you are in stress or tension at that time you don’t find the path which path will go to our goals at that time nobody will come for encouraging to you. No problem, forget everyone. don’t accuse anyone and motivate yourself and boost up your energy move on your goals.

“Don’t lose hope, when the sun goes down, the stars come out ”

“Sometimes you have to encourage yourself if you are the only one going upstream ”

**Appreciate and forgive yourself:**

When we do complete some task properly at that time someone may be appreciated by you or not but you don't forget to appreciate himself. In other hands, you committed a mistake while chasing your goal don’t feel shy or don’t think ‘what I do?’ forgive himself and move in a proper direction.

“Sometimes, good people make a bad choice, it doesn't mean they are bad people, it means they're human ”

**Learn through experience:**

Experience is the best way to learn anything. So, when you try to learn anything or start a new business, you must bean taking the advice from an experienced and expert person of that field because they have passed any kind of situation. they also know what kind of problem are arise and how to tackle it.

"There cannot be any knowledge without experience".

**Stock your abilities and strength:**

It is practically not possible but psychologically we make robust against problems and difficulties. we must try to expand our abilities and strength. while we facing problem at that we psychologically prepared to face the problem due to the stock of our abilities.

“The struggle you’re in today is developing the strength you need for tomorrow”.

Comment: Answers on the site should be only from Hindu perspective. So, you should only cite from Hindu works or related from them. Not from Albert Einstein or other sources which are not related to Hinduism.  Most of your answer discusses about non Hindu works which is suitable on [interpersonalskills.se]. Please [edit] to modify with proper sources.

Answer (score 1):

The Sanskrit equivalent is "anukUla dRkpatha"

kUla is slope or inclination.

The prefix anu is used to denote "that which follows". So anukUla is that which enables you to go down the path you have chosen.

drukpatham is viewpoint.

so anukula drkpatha or positive thinking is that thinking which enables you to reach your goal.

For e.g., if your goal is to have a lasting, healthy meaningful relationship with a friend, or partner or whoever, then it helps to forget faults and remember their good traits. Rama reputedly forgot even great harm (apakAra) that someone may have done to him but would forever remember the slightest favors that they did to him.

If your goal is to achieve a good result in an examination but can't find the motivation to do the work, positive thinking entails keeping your "eyes on the prize" and the decision to break up your studies into smaller portions to be completed each day. In spite of efforts, if you fail, then positive thinking is finding the courage to not give up. Alternatively, it could be making peace with the fact that perhaps another path is better suited for you and pursuing the alternative with vigor.

Essentially positive thinking is that which helps you evolve even in the slightest amount and that which keeps you happy.